# Find Employees who are not promoted in a specific [Month] in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `tblemployees`, in that table I want an output of those employees who are not promoted in a specific month.

```
Create table tblEmployees
(
     Id int Identity Primary key,
     Name nvarchar(40),
     PromotedMonth int
)

----------------------------
| Id | Name | PromotedMonth |
|----|------|---------------|
| 1  | Mark |     03        |
| 2  | Mary |     12        |
-----------------------------
```

I want output like this:

```
----------------------------
| Id | Name | PromotedMonth |
|----|------|---------------|
| 1  | Mark |     March     |
| 2  | Mary |     December  |
-----------------------------
```

Every time I use `DatName` function, it always returns January as `[PromotedMonth]`

So how can I do that?

How to figure out which employee is promoted in a specific month?

Comment: what database? @MANISH KISHORE

Comment: "employees who are not promoted in a specific month", "How to figure out which employee is promoted in a specific month?".  I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

**TestDDL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(10),
  PromotedMonth INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'T',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'T1',12);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, PromotedMonth -1 , CAST('1900-01-01' AS datetime))) AS 'PromotedMonth'
FROM T
```

**Result**

```
| id | name | PromotedMonth |
|----|------|---------------|
|  1 |    T |         March |
|  2 |   T1 |      December |
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69b30/3

Comment: No problem, you can mark this answer if that help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `datename()` function to get month name :

```
select *, datename(month, dateadd(mm, PromotedMonth-1, 0)) 
from tblEmployees e;
```

No need to use `cast()` to do datetime conversation. Just use `0` as unspecified date component to set default date `1900-01-01`.